# Automatic stress marking of Russian text

Tags: resources, ударение

I'd like to be able to take any piece of Russian text and have the stress marks automatically added.  I think this would be a useful tool for learners, but I can't find a site that does this.  Is there one out there?  If there isn't, I'd even consider creating one and would welcome any ideas about how it could be implemented.

Comment: Sometimes the stressing of the word depends on the context. E.g. Он взял большУю коробку (he took a big box) vs. Он взял бОльшую коробку (he took the bigger(implied: of the two) box). замОк(lock) vs. зАмок(castle)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan True, stress-differentiated minimal pairs would be tricky.

Comment: Does anyone know if Grammatica still exists - the program which accents Russian text for you? I lost my stand alone app version when I had to reset Windows 10. A Google search for the online version is 'unable to find the server.' If this company no longer exists are there any alternatives? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [russiangram.com](http://russiangram.com).  It's free and does exactly what you want: add stress marks and dots above the letter Ё.

Comment: +1 for the link. However for some reason is skips stress in some words (I've tried *дорогой*, *того*, *посажу*, *замок*). I could understand it for the words with meaning-dependent stress. But what about *того*, *посажу*?..

Comment: This website is in active development.  I have only worked on it for a couple of weeks and the domain name was registered literally just yesterday.  I have started out with adding nouns and adjectives. Pronouns were added just now (try _того_ again). Verbs and proper names are next on my list. Give me a bit of time ;) Thanks for upvoting!

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize it was your own project. Well done but keep going!

Comment: Since there is no contact point on the site, I'll post here (sorry admins, but we should support this activity I think). Translations don't always work, but you probably know it. What would be a nice additional feature is to add the IPA-based transcription, if possible.

Comment: @texnic: Added my contacts and a Google group.

Comment: RussianGram does not preserve line-breaks either (at least on OS X.)

Answer (score 4):

Not an online application, still:

[RussAcc](http://bzsoft.spb.ru/russacc.html)

> Программа RussAcc предназначена для озвучивания текстов, создания аудиокниг (в формате wav, mp3, amr, aac + плейлист m3u), расстановки ударений (Nicolai, Alyona, Loquendo) в русских текстах (отсюда и ее название - сокращенное Russian Accents), удобного чтения книг с экрана. Можно использовать RussAcc как редактор текста, конвертор FB2 в TXT. Заяц русак, как известно, способен быстро ударять по барабану, RussAcc же очень быстро расставляет ударения в текстах.

For the record, I'm not affiliated with them, but used the tool some time ago. It seems to be quite nice (except for the edge cases).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.grammatica.eu/ is probably the best software of this sort, and the upcoming second vesion should make it even better. It's quite expensive, but I can highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a stress marker on my personal website. It searches for words [here](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morphque.cgi?flags=endnnnnp) and matches the words given with regex. It doesn't matter if the word is conjugated or not, but keep in mind that it can't distinguish between `Облака` or `облакА`, for instance. And before searching, you need to make it lowercase and remove the dots from `ё`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [free open source program](https://github.com/Vuizur/add-stress-to-epub) to automatically mark the stress of Russian ebooks (also considering grammar).

I haven't published the benchmarks yet, but they indicate that it is as at least as good or even better than Russiangram, which is commercial for longer texts.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should mention your goal in your post.   For instance, if you would like to read something with stress marks, there are plenty of texts available for you--should you be adept at combing through the internet and resources published by Russians for foreigners, or even for children.   If you would like to mark something up with stress marks, then this brings me to my third concern.   If you are worried about missing the stress marks since you are still developing your Russian, then you may want to consider the fact that this problem will hammer itself out with time, and not just through reading--you may need to include a triangulated strategy of listening to things, a chart you make or have of some of the unexpected shifts in stress/accent (or one you've found), and a text along the same level where these words will likely appear.   However, if you feel like your Russian is on a nice level where you more or less know the stress marks, and are still anxious about a few exceptions, it's time to take off the training wheels and ride with the big boys.