# Grammatica program

Tags: грамматика

Does anyone know if Grammatica still exists - the program which accents Russian text for you? I lost my stand alone app version when I had to reset Windows 10. A Google search for the online version is 'unable to find the server.' If this company no longer exists are there any alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: See https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/332/2104

Comment: The website stopped working about a month ago. I've been trying to find some info on what happened and if its coming back up, but no luck. They had a pretty expensive subscription model. There are other sites out there for stress marks - RussianGram and Russian Stress - but none that provide all the cases and other grammatical info this one did.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes- their grammatical information was invaluable. I still have trouble identifying participles- although so far the morfologia site does a good job as long as you already have a basic grasp of the grammar.

Comment: although visual info is indeed very convenient, one can always paste a text into Google Translate and listen to the playback of any given word

Comment: it's not a question about Russian language

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Russiangram for a few days now in order to replace Grammatica. Very well done and very helpful! The one question I have now is how to choose when it gives you an option. eg: Вели́ка|Велика́. The morfilogia site helps somewhat and also a book I have 5000 Russian words. But one of the most helpful things about Grammatica with its drop down tables was that it made the choice quite easy.

Comment: i guess the choice of the correct stress needs to be informed by knowledge of the grammar